# Cargar campo Select Multilple con Jquery para editar registro

Tags: php, jquery, select

Tengo un codigo con un link con varioas campos data- asi:

```
<a id ="Editando" class="Editador" data-nombrepuesto = "<?php echo $row['NombrePuesto'];?>"data-ubicacionpuesto = "<?php echo $row['UbicacionPuesto'];?>" data-software="<?php echo $row['Software'];?>" href="#" title="Editar Publicacion."><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a
```

> Al hacer click en en link levanto con JQuery
>   asi

```
 $('.Editador').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();        
    $('#NombrePuesto').val($(this).data('nombrepuesto'));
    $('#UbicacionPuesto').val($(this).data('ubicacionpuesto'));
    var Softwareador = $(this).data('software'); 
    $('#myModalFormPuesto1').modal({show:true});
```

> El tema es que software tiene estos datos: EG/EX/SA .. que son los valores del multiple select. Yo se separar los datos en un array, pero no logro cargar el campo select, que es multiple,  con dichas opciones seleccionadas en el campo del formulario modal que se llama Software[]
>   Me podran ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma sencilla para seleccionar opciones es recorrer el `array` de las opciones de sofware, creado con `split`, con `each` y añadir el atributo seleccionado.

```js
$('.Editador').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();        
    console.log("editando...");
     $('#NombrePuesto').val($(this).data('nombrepuesto'));
   $('#UbicacionPuesto').val($(this).data('ubicacionpuesto'));
    var Softwareador = $(this).data('software');
    var resultsSoft = Softwareador.split("/");
    $.each(resultsSoft, function(i, v) {
      console.log(v);
      $("#Softwareador option[value="+ v +"]").attr("selected",true);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id ="Editando" class="Editador" data-nombrepuesto = "NombrePuesto" data-ubicacionpuesto = "UbicacionPuesto" data-software="EG/EX/SA" href="#" title="Editar Publicacion.">Editar</a>

<form>
 <input type="text" name="NombrePuesto" id="NombrePuesto"/>
 <input type="text" name="UbicacionPuesto" id="UbicacionPuesto"/>
 <select name="Softwareador" id="Softwareador" multiple>
   <option name="AB" value="AB">AB</option>
   <option name="EG" value="EG">EG</option>
   <option name="EX" value="EX">EX</option>
   <option name="HB" value="HB">HB</option>
   <option name="SA" value="SA">SA</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Comment: EXCELENTE GRACIASSSSS